# ¿Como agregar datos almacenados en un arreglo a un TableView en JavaFX?

Tags: arraylist, javafx

Estoy haciendo un programa que toma las notas de las actividades de un curso de estudiantes para luego calcular el valor final de la nota para cada corte del ciclo educativo (3 cortes en total, 3 notas finales que calcular). Para calcular la nota final de cada corte se toman en cuenta las notas de las actividades designadas para ese corte, las cuales varian en cantidad ya que el usuario puede agregar o quitar una actividad siempre que lo desee. Las notas de cada actividad son ingresadas directamente en un TableView, y desde aqui deben ser enviadas a una Clase Estudiante que procesa los calculos necesarios para la nota final del corte.

El problema es el siguiente, como las actividades varian, la cantidad de notas evaluadas tambien lo hacen, por lo que me veo obligado a declarar un arreglo de notas por cada corte (3 arreglos que contienen todas las notas que el usuario ingrese por la tabla), pero no encuentro la manera de setear el CellFactory a las columnas de las notas para que cada una tome un elemento especifico del arreglo.

Esta es la clase estudiantes, cada nota ingresada en la tabla debe ser almacenada en uno de los 3 arrayList
creados para cada corte.

```
public class Estudiantes {

private String Nombre;



private ArrayList<Float> notasPrimerCorte;
private ArrayList<Float> notasSegundoCorte;
private ArrayList<Float> notasTercerCorte;

public Estudiantes(String nombre) {
    Nombre = nombre;
    this.notasPrimerCorte = new ArrayList<>();
    this.notasSegundoCorte = new ArrayList<>();
    this.notasTercerCorte = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Busque por todo internet y no hay nada que explique como hacerlo asi que tuve que releer toda la documentacion de tableViews y cellFactories, pero al final di con la solucion, aqui el codigo:

```
    public void generarColumna(String Title, TableView tab, int Index){
    TableColumn<Estudiantes, Float> column = new TableColumn<>(Title);
    column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().getNotasPrimerCorte().get(Index)));
    column.setMinWidth(500);
    column.setMaxWidth(500);
    tab.getColumns().add(column);
}
```